# Right approach against time-dependent test data (or test data becoming stale gradually)

Tags: python, unit-testing, tdd

I decided to use TDD approach in my project. As a start, I focused on a small part of a use case:
**Validate AccessCode.**
An AccessCode, a date in Julian format, is valid if it is less than or equal to today.

*Step 1: Write a test*

```
def test_should_validate_accessdate(self):
    assert application.is_accessdate_valid(56746)
```

*Step 2: Run to fail*
Done.

*Step 3: Make the test pass*
In application.py,

```
def is_accessdate_valid(accessdate):
    return True
```

*Step 4: Run to pass*
Done.

*Step 5: Refactor*
There is nothing to refactor. But, the hard-coded return value sucks.

Now, repeat:
*Step 1: Write a new test*

```
def test_should_invalidate_accessdate(self):
    assert not application.is_accessdate_valid(54990)
```

*Step 2: Run to fail*
Done.

*Step 3: Make the test pass*
In this case, the hard-coded return value is a pain. So, I need to remove it, instead generalizing some logic for the tests to pass.

```
def is_accessdate_valid(accessdate):
    today_julian = julian_to_julian5(calendar_to_julian(datetime.utcnow()))
    return accessdate >= today_julian
```

I am not still sure if I did the right thing by taking such a huge leap in one step. But, I saw no other way to make the test pass without failing the other test.
Suggestions are welcome here.

*Step 4: Run to pass the test*
Done.

*Step 5: Run to pass all the tests*
Done.

Initially, I was proud that I was able to define a function by writing a test for it first, and then shaping it up through more test(s).
However, later I realized that the test that checks for valid accessdate will start failing once today's date crosses the input accessdoday's date.
One thing I could do is to provide a dynamically calculated input accessdate:
1. Add a day or two to today's date.
2. Convert the above resulting date to julian format.
3. Use the above Julian result as input accessdate.

However, something doesn't feel right there.

Am I going on the right path here?
Or did I go astray in between somewhere?
Or the function design wrong in the first place, assuming that I should have chosen a different signature instead?

Any suggestions or thrashing are welcome.

Comment: Are `julian_to_julian5` and `calendar_to_julian` covered by tests? If so, you can use them in this test. Alternatively, consider mocking `utcnow()` to always give a preselected point in time.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: Yes, you could consider both those methods as part of a well-tested module. So, what you are saying is my solution of providing dynamically calculated input is good enough. Correct?

Comment: Yes, I would say that was fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to write unit tests that are time-dependent. So write tests that are relative to a date that is an argument - thus stays constant - or use the mocking approach mentioned by jonrsharpe. This leaves you only the problem of determining whether your mechanism for determining the time-dependent component works, but not whether the logic works.

This applies to other environmental things as well - machine names, directory pathnames, historical stock prices, etc.

Comment: The argument being passed to the fubction is a date itself, just in Julian format. I could use that for relativity.

Comment: Good. It is good to see people thinking about this. Having tests that have to be changed just because of the passage of time would be bad. Many just don't bother, which leaves huge untested chunks of code. Very good question.